# In what version of dom4j, org.dom4j.Document has a method of asXML?

Tags: java, dom4j

In what version of dom4j, org.dom4j.Document has a method of asXML? I have tried different versions as the following, however, no one is correct. Thanks.

```
dom4j-1.4.jar
dom4j-1.5.jar
dom4j-1.5.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dom4j-2.0.3.jar
dom4j-2.1.4.jar
```

The code looks like the follows:

```
org.dom4j.Document doc = ...;
String xml = doc.asXML();
```

There are code snippets using org.dom4j.Document.asXML at https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.dom4j.Document/asXML

Comment: What do you mean with "no one is correct"? Missing or incorrect behavior? As far as I can recall, `Node#asXML()` has been there from the start (at least from 1.4), and `Document` is a `Node`.